# date range picker and calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a hotel booking form that calculates the prices per person depending on number of adults, seniors and students. I want to include a date range picker that will calculate the total cost depending on number of days selected but the when i include a second calendar, it does not show (no drop down). How can I include the second calendar that will allow selection of the end date and calculate the total cost?

```js
update_amounts();
$('select').change(update_amounts);

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#tickets > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
    var amount = (qty * price);
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.subtotal').text('$' + amount);
  });
  $('#total').val('$' + sum);
  $('#total').val('$')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Adult</strong><a href="#" class="tooltip-1" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="16 - 65 years old"><sup class="icon-info-4"></sup></a>
          <span class="price">3,400</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="adults" id="adults">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">ksh 0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Senior</strong><a href="#" class="tooltip-1" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Over 65 years old"><sup class="icon-info-4">
    
                                                </sup></a><span class="price">3,400</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="senior" id="senior">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">$0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Student >15 yrs</strong> <span class="price">2,000</span> </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="student" id="student">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">$0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label>From?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_pick" name="date_pick" data-date-format="M d, D" placeholder="Select a date">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>To?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_pick" name="date_pick" data-date-format="M d, D" placeholder="Select a date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name and Lastname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_lastname_booking" name="name_lastname_booking" placeholder="Name and Lastname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_booking" name="email_booking" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Telephone</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone_booking" name="telephone_booking" placeholder="Telephone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group add_bottom_30">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Book now" class="btn_full" id="submit-booking">
    </div>


    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Missing some stuff. Your form does not have and opening tag, same with the table.

Comment: Can you try turning it into a [StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, I inserted a beginning  tag after the end of the table, and inserted the missing closing `<div>` tag at the end of your form-groups. The inputs that you have noted to accept dates were set to type "text". I changed these two to `input type="date"`
Now the calendar dropdown shows on both inputs. You can use js to [calculate the difference between the two selected dates](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html), and calculate according to the relevant prices. 
Alternatively you could use something like the open-source [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) tool by Dan Grossman if you would prefer to choose both dates in one picking.

Hope this helps.

```js
update_amounts();
$('select').change(update_amounts);

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#tickets > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
    var amount = (qty * price);
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.subtotal').text('$' + amount);
  });
  $('#total').val('$' + sum);
  $('#total').val('$')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Adult</strong><a href="#" class="tooltip-1" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="16 - 65 years old"><sup class="icon-info-4"></sup></a>
          <span class="price">3,400</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="adults" id="adults">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">ksh 0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Senior</strong><a href="#" class="tooltip-1" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Over 65 years old"><sup class="icon-info-4">
    
                                                </sup></a><span class="price">3,400</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="senior" id="senior">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">$0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Student >15 yrs</strong> <span class="price">2,000</span> </td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select">
            <select class="form-control" name="student" id="student">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="subtotal">$0</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>From?</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_pick" name="date_pick" data-date-format="M d, D" placeholder="Select a date">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>To?</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_pick" name="date_pick" data-date-format="M d, D" placeholder="Select a date">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name and Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_lastname_booking" name="name_lastname_booking" placeholder="Name and Lastname">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_booking" name="email_booking" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone_booking" name="telephone_booking" placeholder="Telephone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group add_bottom_30">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Book now" class="btn_full" id="submit-booking">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</body>
```